Send Email action: 0 recipients Error
Why send email action in triggered flow, must specifies the recipient ID and Email template even if in my case I want to send email to a specific email address add to a list?
if I didn't specify them, I get this error:
Case: case escalation for Customer services” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. 0 recipients Error ID: 125666289-12433 (-1927571512)0 recipients Error ID: 125666289-12433 (-1927571512)



In terms of the Email Template ID part of your question, you either need to use the Email Body OR the Email Template ID. You are using the body so it should be fine.
Regards to the Recipient ID again that is optional. If you use it, you need to pass a single Contact or Lead record ID. This field gets required if you choose to pass an Email Template ID.
Is the recipientEmailText variable a collection? It should be a collection that includes the emails as text. And not a single string.

the Recipient address list does not accept collection, the recipient address collection accept the collection and tried it and did not work as well.
